# How to convert Alphanumeric String to NUMBER String or NUMBER?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to convert alphanumeric string into Number. The alphanumeric string contains Numeric Digits Set [0-9], Capital Letters Set [A-Z] and Small Letters Set [a-z] respectively to numbers [00-09], [10-35] and [36-62].

Per Single Letter or Digit it has to generate Two Digit, if the letter is 'y' then number will be '61' or the letter is 'C' then number will be '12' or the digit is '6' then number will be '06'.

For Example:

Alphanumeric String: "yc69CJjVvf"

NUMBER: 61380609121945315841

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create plist where you have to manually enter data for Digits Set [0-9], Capital Letters Set [A-Z] and Small Letters Set [a-z].

See image below.

[image]

And create one for loop where you have to pass the alpha bate value.and you will get the number for that .

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                      @"YourPlistName" ofType:@"plist"];

    NSMutableArray *arrData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSMutableArray *arrCode=[arrData valueForKey:@"code"];
    NSMutableArray *arrname=[arrData valueForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *code = [[NSString alloc] init];


    for (int i=0;i<[arrname count];i++)
    {

        if ([[arrname objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:StrAplahbates])//StrAplahbates is the string for which you want number value.
        {
            [code appendFormat:@"%@",arrCode [i]];



        }
    }
```

May be it will help you.

Comment: @ParthPatel Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can create NSMutableDictionary with Character->Number AND Number->Character, then you can go through the string and convert strings, 
example:

```
NSMutableDictionary *stringToNumbersDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *numberToStringDIctionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for(int i = 0;i <= 9; i++) {
    NSString *keyWithZero = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d",i];
    NSString *keyWithoutZero = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];

    // So you can look up with 06 and 6 to get the number-string
    [stringToNumbersDictionary setObject:keyWithZero forKey:keyWithoutZero];
    [numberToStringDIctionary setObject:keyWithoutZero forKey:keyWithZero];
}

// from ASCII A to ASCII Z
for(int i = 65;i <= 90;i++) {
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",i];
    NSString *numberKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];

    [stringToNumbersDictionary setObject:numberKey forKey:key];
    [numberToStringDIctionary setObject:key forKey:numberKey];
}

// from ASCII a to ASCII z
for(int i = 97;i <= 122;i++) {
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",i];
    NSString *numberKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];

    [stringToNumbersDictionary setObject:numberKey forKey:key];
    [numberToStringDIctionary setObject:key forKey:numberKey];
}
```

To convert string to Number-string you can use

```
- (NSString *)numberStringWithString:(NSString *)string {
    NSMutableString *result = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for(NSInteger index = 0;index < string.length;index++) {
        unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:index];
        NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",c];
        [result appendString:stringToNumbersDictionary[key]];
    }
    return result;
}
```

And to convert it back

```
- (NSString *)stringWithNumberString:(NSString *)numberString {
    NSMutableString *result = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for(NSInteger index = 0;index < numberString.length;index+=2) {
        NSString *key = [numberString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(index, 2)];
        [result appendString:numberToStringDIctionary[key]];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to through the string by char, if char is symbol convert to number string, if char is number than format("0%d") and accumulate results to one string and than convert to number.

Comment: i have tried the format (0%d) for the number but it also adds 'S' to the number... For example number is '1' then it gives '01S', but i only want '01'

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake... That perfectly works for the digit [0-9]... Thanks but what about letters?

Comment: Make some table of letter and their codes, or make array and get index than add delta (for example A has idx=0 than code=idx+detla, where delta=10)